# Javascript string equals on of these symbols

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to evaluate if a string is equal to one of these symbols `|\~+`

But this doesn't work:

```
var a = 'abcted',
    b = '|\~+';

if( a !== b ){
}
```

So if `a` is equal to one of the symbols in `b`, is evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Are you doing a string to string comparison, or are you trying to see if any one singular character in b is in the string a?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if one string contains another substring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply check if one string contains another using the method `indexOf`:

```
var b = '|\~+';
if (b.indexOf(a) == -1) {
  // b doesn't contain a
}
```

A new suggestion is made for the function [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), which would work like this, but not (yet) in many browsers.

```
var b = '|\~+';
if (!b.includes(a)) {
  // b doesn't contain a
}
```

Comment: This will work only if the entire string `a` is in `b`. If `a` is a substring of `b`

Comment: That is what was asked: *".. if a string is equal to one of these symbols"*

Comment: Its not very clear what OP is trying to do. If we look at the  example, `a` is not a single character string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Regular Expression to solve this, like this

```
if (/[|\\~\+]/.test(a) === false) {
    // `a` doesn't contain any of the symbols.
}
```

`[|\\~\+]` checks if any of the characters in the character group is in `a`. If none of them are there then `test` will return `false`.

```
console.log(/[|\\~\+]/.test("abcted"));
// false
console.log(/[|\\~\+]/.test("abc|ted"));
// true
console.log(/[|\\~\+]/.test("abc\\ted"));
// true
console.log(/[|\\~\+]/.test("abc~ted"));
// true
console.log(/[|\\~\+]/.test("abc+ted"));
// true
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use RegEx where possible, but for those who are not wanting to:

```
var a = 'abcted',
    b = '|\~+';

for (var i = 0, len = b.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (a.indexOf(b[i]))  
    {   
        alert(b[i]);
    }
}
```